# Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system:

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, cpanel

I am trying to follow this [guide](https://clients.temok.com/knowledgebase.php?action=displayarticle&id=524) to install python modules however i don't seem to have virtual environment or pip installed so im trying to get those to continue.

Python 2.7.5 is installed on my cpanel, i want to install extra modules for my scripts. I download:

`get-pip.py` using `curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py`

I then try running the python file with:

`python get-pip.py`

It starts but fails at: `Installing collected packages: pip, wheel`.
With error message:

> Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip'

If i use `sudo python get-pip.py`

I get the following error message:

> jailshell: sudo: command not found

Thanks

Comment: did you try with `sudo`?

Comment: using sudo i get: jailshell: sudo: command not found

Comment: which OS are you using?

Comment: probably this can be helpful : https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/issues/209
if you are using virtual env

Comment: its cPanel so how do i find out? @liorko

Comment: I am trying to instal pip so i can install virtual environment so i can install modules. @RoshanBagdiya

Comment: Try to install pip on your device. That s the way how it should work. Python was build up to provide always one solution for a problem.

Comment: But I need to install pip on cPanel which I'm having trouble doing so that I can run python programs on cPanel so that they can communicate with MySQL as my cPanel does not support remote MySQL. @dl.meteo

Answer (score 6):

I'd the same problem in my ChromeOS and I couldn't solve it running `chmod -R` in my `site-packages` folder. To solve it I had to install `pip` only for my user running:

```
python get-pip.py --user
```

The only problem is that you have to run pip as a python module `python -m pip`, but you can create an alias inside your `.bashrc`.

```
# ~/.bashrc
#
# ...
alias pip="python -m pip"
```

Answer (score 3):

Run this issue on my local MacOS with pip2.7, trying to install jwt package

```
sudo pip2.7 install jwt pyjwt[crypto]
...
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/...'
...
..
```

No sudo or trying to chmod the read-only file helped. Solved installation with **--user** parameter:

```
sudo pip2.7 install --user jwt pyjwt[crypto]
```